# Is it possible to make sql calls using aws lambda functions to an external oracle database that’s not stored in the aws environment

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, oracle, aws-lambda, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i look this up most resources are on making the sql calls to a db instance within aws but for my case I don’t want to have the database in aws as it is already set up in oracle

I also saw some information on aws rds but nothing on what I’m trying to do

Comment: You have to provide connection parameters for the database client while establishing a connection. They may point to any (accessible) instance

Answer (score 0):

The remote Oracle database would need to be accessible from the Internet.

If the AWS Lambda function does not need to communicate with any resources in a VPC, then **do *NOT* configure it for a VPC** -- this will grant the Lambda function access to the Internet.

You may need to **configure security settings** (eg IP whitelist) on the Oracle database to permit access from the Internet. The IP address of the AWS Lambda function will vary a lot unless you configure the Lambda function to use a VPC with a NAT Gateway (extra costs apply) and an Elastic IP address.

Please note that having your database remote to an application will **increase the latency** (decrease the speed) when accessing the database. It is generally recommended to keep the database close to the application.

Your code in the AWS Lambda function should connect to the Oracle database in exactly the same way that you would connect via code from your own computer.